# Python Pandas: Counting how many times value from one data frame appears in another dataframe, filering on multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I have a question. I am trying to count how many times values from df1:

```
Record
v:12:14
v:14:18
v:15:19
```

appear in df2, when df2 is filter on multiple conditions:

```
df2:
Patient Test    Treatment   Record
1   A   15  v:12:14
2   A   30  v:14:18
3   C   15  v:15:19
4   C   20  v:15:19
1   B   15  v:12:14
2   B   15  v:14:18
3   A   20  v:12:14
4   B   30  v:15:19
```

Essentially ending in a matrix like this:

```
Patient Record  A:15    A:30    C:15    C:20    B:15    A:20    B:30
1   v:12:14 1   0   0   0   1   1   0
2   v:14:18 0   1   0   0   1   0   0
3   v:15:19 0   0   1   1   0   0   1
4   v:15:19 0   0   1   1   0   0   1
3   v:12:14 1   0   0   0   1   1   0
```

Does anyone have any ideas? I am doing it now by iterating two data frames, but I feel like it can be done faster and better.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: You can join two tables by join ```df1.join(df2, on='record')```. What I do not understand is the logic behind the last table. What are those? Patient 1 has a A:15 but in the last table you have A:20 marked 1

Comment: The Code Snippet feature is mostly useless in my opinion.

Comment: There are 8 total "appearances" of df1 values in df2, but there are 14 `1` values in expected output. Why?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a [pivot table](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html):

```py
matrix = df2.pivot_table(
    index=['Patient', 'Record'],
    columns=['Test', 'Treatment'],
    aggfunc='size',
).fillna(0).astype(int)
```

Output:

```sh
Test             A        B     C   
Treatment       15 20 30 15 30 15 20
Patient Record                      
1       v:12:14  1  0  0  1  0  0  0
2       v:14:18  0  0  1  1  0  0  0
3       v:12:14  0  1  0  0  0  0  0
        v:15:19  0  0  0  0  0  1  0
4       v:15:19  0  0  0  0  1  0  1
```